# Conitnue after asking for permission Android Studio

Tags: java, android

**CODE:**

```java
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 1);

driverList = new ArrayList < > ();
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/drivers.json");

if (!file.exists()) {
   try {
      file.createNewFile();
      ServerTask st = new ServerTask("2019", true);
      st.execute();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
} else {
   load();
}
```

So I have this code and after I have installed the app and I was asked for the permission the App doesn't continue. I always accept the permission

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided here only states the checks on the required permissions anda call to request them. Please post the code for `requestPermissions` method

Also try the following

1. You must implement onRequestPermissionResult method in your activity
2. In that method you verify that  the permissions are now granted
3. Finally perform the action you need to achieve.

If you have already done that then pls post that code snippet here.

[Refer to this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)